# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: vb.net

I've seen this answered multiple times and I think I know what the problem is but in my case the solution makes no sense to me.

I get the following error:

```
    An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\llexl\Desktop\Test\Encrypted String.txt' because it is being used by another process.
```

I separated two parts of the code into their own buttons to troubleshoot and the first part that is responsible for creating files works just fine, but the second part of the code responsible for editing the files and renaming them is when this error happens which to me makes no sense since `System.IO.File.Create` shouldn't need to be closed as far as I know.

Anyways here is the code that's giving me trouble:

```
   Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        TextBox2.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
        TextBox2.AppendText("\Encrypted String.txt")
        System.IO.File.Create(TextBox2.Text)


        TextBox3.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
        TextBox3.AppendText("\masterkey.txt")
        System.IO.File.Create(TextBox3.Text)

    End Sub
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        Dim file2 As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(TextBox2.Text, True)

        file.Write(RichTextBox1.Text)
        file.Close()
        file2 = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(TextBox3.Text, True)
        file2.Write(TextBox1.Text)
        file2.Close()
        My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(TextBox3.Text, "masterkey.perlpron")
        My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(TextBox2.Text, "Encrypted String.perlpron")
        MsgBox("Library ready", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End Sub
```

I'd appreciate some help :)

Comment: I'd add a .Dispose() to the Create sentence, just in case...
_System.IO.File.Create(TextBox2.Text).Dispose()_

Comment: Well, you could know you are at least 20% wrong from the way your program behaves.  You make it 100% by looking at the File.Create documentation in MSDN.  It is a Function, unique in that its return value must **never** be ignored.  Not only is it bug, it is also a *drastically* bad practice.  If your program ends for any reason before it completed writing the file then you've just left a landmine, ready to blow up in any unsuspecting program that expects that file to contain *something*.  Unclear why you'd do this, only sensible alternative is File.Delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested this and the File.Create-method is the one causing this behavior. It's not ment to be used like you are using it. [Create-method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx) opens a stream for the file and you are never closing that.

Easy fix is to remove the Create-method-call since the OpenTextFileWriter already creates the file if it does not exist.

So remove lines

```
System.IO.File.Create(TextBox2.Text)
System.IO.File.Create(TextBox3.Text)
```

And you are good to go.

Id also just use System.IO.StreamWriter with using-block to simplify the code and to be sure it's disposed properly:

```
    Using file As New System.IO.StreamWriter(TextBox2.Text, True)
        file.Write(RichTextBox1.Text)
    End Using

    Using file2 As New System.IO.StreamWriter(TextBox3.Text, True)
        file2.Write(TextBox1.Text)
    End Using
```